# Avoiding Job.Wait() and async void when using Parallel.Invoke or an alternative for parallel calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing, parallel.invoke

I am writing an integration test where I want to avoid a `.Wait()` call

```
public void MyTest_MultiClient_NoException()
{
    Action action = () => Reader.Read(@"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.data").Wait();
    var actions = Enumerable.Repeat(action, 1000).ToArray();

    Parallel.Invoke(actions);
}
```

or `async void` as being warned by Visual Studio (*"Avoid using 'async' lambda when delegate type returns 'void'*). The async void is in *Action action = async () ...*

```
public void MyTest_MultiClient_NoException()
{
    Action action = async () => await Reader.Read(@"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.data");
    var actions = Enumerable.Repeat(action, 1000).ToArray();

    Parallel.Invoke(actions);
}
```

I use a Mutex in `Reader.Read`. Therefore, I want to simulate a multi client environment using `Parallel.Invoke` (or an alternative for parallel calls) in order to test for a TimeOutException.

`Reader.Read` returns an awaitable class `Job<TResult>`.

```
public static class Reader
{
    public static Job<XYZ> Read() =>
        new Job<XYZ>(Task.FromResult(new XYZ()));

}
```

```
public class Job<TResult>
{
    public Job<TResult>(Task<TResult> task) => this.task = task;
    private readonly Task<TResult> task;
    public TResult Wait() => task.Result;
    public TaskAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter() => task.GetAwaiter();
}
```

```
public class XYZ {}
```

I have tried switching to a `Func<Job<TResult>>` instead of the `Action`, but `Parallel.Invoke` has no overloads for that.

Comment: There's no `async void` in this code. What is `Reader.Read` and what does it return? If you want to run anything in the background, why are you using what looks like `Task.Wait()` only to try to run the blocked task in yet another thread? That's 2 or 3 threads wasted trying to do the job of one

Comment: Post code that actually reproduces the problem. The error you describe doesn't match your code. Besides, if you want to run a *synchronous* method in the background, you need `Task.Run`. If you want to start multiple asynchronous methods, do so, store the tasks,  then await all of them with `await Task.WhenAll`, eg `var tasks=Enumerable.Range(0,100).Select(_=>Reader.Read(@"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.data")); await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`. There are better, more practical ways too, like storing the paths in a list then using `await Parallel.ForEachAsync(files,(file,ct)=>Reader.Read(file));`

Comment: `Reader.Read` returns an awaitable class `Job<Tresult>`. I cannot post any code from Reader. The async void is in `Action action = async () => await Reader.Read(@"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.data");`

Comment: `var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(_ => ReportReader.ReadFromFile(@"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.data")); await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` dosens't work because `Reader.Read` returns `Job<TResult>`. It's actually jobs, not tasks.

Comment: Which is why you need to post the missing code. We can't guess what `Reader.Read` is, what `Job.Wait` returns, or where `async void` is used. There's no `Reader.Read` or `Job<TResult>` in .NET itself

Comment: I suspect you get the warning at `Action action = () => ...`, not `Parallel.Invoke`. If `Wait()` returns a `Task`, the only way `Action action = () =>` can compile is for the delegate to have an `async void` signature. Change the signature to `Func<Task> func=()=>...` and use `await.Task.WhenAll(funcs);` to await all those tasks. If your code runs any expensive code before yielding you can use `Task.Run(()=>Reader.Read(....).Wait()` to start running your code in the background

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Reader.Read` return an awaitable type, you could `await` it and project it to a `Task<TResult>` with the [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) LINQ operator. Then wait all the tasks with the [`Task.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall) method.

```
public void MyTest_MultiClient_NoException()
{
    Task<TResult>[] tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
        .Select(async _ => await Reader.Read(@"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.data"))
        .ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

In case the `Reader.Read` call blocks the current thread for a considerable amount of time, or you want to parallelize it for testing purposes, you could offload it to the `ThreadPool` with the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method:

```
        .Select(_ => Task.Run(async () => await Reader.Read(@"C:\MyFolder\MyFile.data")))
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach actually works. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote your answer yet.